# JW Player getDuration() always returns 0

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

I need to get the duration of HLS video on loading of the JWPlayer. When I try to use `getDuration()` method, I always get 0 as the response whereas the actual duration is 1:50:47. Is there any way I can get this done?